# Sequence of images to video in OpenCV + range of reading

Tags: python, image, opencv, video

Already fighting with this problem for a whole day, maybe anyone can help? Have a basic knowledge at Mathlab, python and openCV
I am use python for make a video from images. And, as usually, found a problem with it. There is no sequence in reading image's for writing video. For example i have img_01,img_02,.....img_n. Each img - frame of video. And at final video it's looks like:

./img_155.jpg
./img_476.jpg
./img_282.jpg
and etc.

So, it's totally chaotic at the final video, as result...
Is anyone can help, please, with this problem? I found a lot of hints, but all of them with c++ only. There is code, what i am using now:

```
import cv2
import argparse
import os

# Construct the argument parser and parse the arguments
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument("-ext", "--extension", required=False, default='jpg', help="extension name. default is 'png'.")
ap.add_argument("-o", "--output", required=False, default='output.mp4', help="output video file")
args = vars(ap.parse_args())

# Arguments
dir_path = '.'
ext = args['extension']
output = args['output']

images = []
for f in os.listdir(dir_path):
    if f.endswith(ext):
        images.append(f)

# Determine the width and height from the first image
image_path = os.path.join(dir_path, images[0])
frame = cv2.imread(image_path)
cv2.imshow('video',frame)
height, width, channels = frame.shape

# Define the codec and create VideoWriter object
fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'mp4v') # Be sure to use lower case
out = cv2.VideoWriter(output, fourcc, 30.0, (width, height))

for image in images:

    image_path = os.path.join(dir_path, image)
    frame = cv2.imread(image_path)

    out.write(frame) # Write out frame to video

    cv2.imshow('video',frame)
    if (cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF) == ord('q'): # Hit `q` to exit
        break

# Release everything if job is finished
out.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

print("The output video is {}".format(output))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is : for f in os.listdir(dir_path): return file name in random sequence.

You should add follow line before '# Determine the width and height from the first image'

```
def name2num(name):
   m = re.search('img_(\d+)\.?.*', name)
   return int(m.group(1),10)

images.sort(key=name2num)
```

Comment: Oh great, its worked! But now have another problem, order is going well, but: img_188........img_189.......img_19. Well, it look's like 19 shoulnd't be here, haha. What the way to fight with this problem?

Comment: Solve this problem by renaming of file, king of img_%03d

Comment: If you feel my answer help you, would you mind help to vote it?

Comment: Of course, buddy! I tried to vote for it a lot of times, but because i have less, that 15 reputation i cant do it T_T